# How do I use for loop with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Hello I am a self taught developer and I am trying to use a for() loop with jQuery, but it does not seem to work. I am trying to loop through an array of RGB colors, that are hard coded for now with strings. Here is a snippet below on what I am trying to accomplish. I want each div to contain a diffrent

http://jsfiddle.net/CleverOscarDev/cyztq6m5/

```
var squares = $(".squares");
var colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
]

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors;
}
```

Comment: This line `squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors` is assigning the whole array. Instead, you should assign `color[i]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0xdwhsnc/

You missed the index, instead of colors use colors[i]

```
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
 squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

Comment: more specific : `colors[i % colors.length]`

Answer (score 1):

If your colors array is going to have same number of colors as the number of div.s with class square you can do this!

```
$(".squares").each(function(key, value) {
    $(this).css({"background-color" : colors[key]});
});
```

Comment: You're setting on each iteration a given color for all squares at the same time

Comment: Updated the answer. thanks for the heads up @RobertoMaldonado

Answer (score 1):

Try each loop. http://jsfiddle.net/cyztq6m5/15/

```
$(squares).each(function(key, value) {
  value.style.backgroundColor = colors[key];       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a simple error, `colors` is an array, not a color string, so you should use `colors[i]`

```
for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use jquery for each

```
$.each(squares, function(idx, square){
    square.style.backgroundColor=colors[idx]
});
```